# getting the elements of a Collections.Generic through refllection

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, mono

I am currently working on a class that given a link to a root object go though, and gets all the things that class points to, and then creates a printout so that it can be filtered through, and searched to find things like null pointers, and multiple things referencing the same object.

I have been able to do the majority of this by using LINQ, and reflection, except for being able to look into the elements of a List, or Dictionary.

using reflection I can get to that it is `typeof(List<"someClass">)`, or typeof(Dictionary<"someOtherClass">). this matter might sound trivial (as the type the list contains should be known), but in many places in the current benchmark program there are any number of Lists, and Dictionaries that may contain almost any class object in the assembly.

the question is: how would I go from a stored FieldInfo which I can test to find that it has the typeof one of these Collections.Generic then using reflection get to the elements of the collection, so that I can get the FieldInfo of the elements?

**edit code**

```
// behave is a pointer to a System.object
// infoList is a List<fieldInfo> that belong to behave
string DisplayFields(){
    string _str = "";
    List<FieldInfo> _newList = infoList; 
    if(_newList != null && _newList.count > 0){
        foreach(FieldInfo info in _newList){
            if(info.FieldType.ToString().Contains(".List")){
                _str += "\t" + info.Name;
                _str += ".typeof(" + info.FieldType + "): ";
                _str += ((info.GetValue(behave)!=null)?info.GetValue(behave):"null");
                _str += "\n";
                // this is where the work on List should happen
            }else if(info.FieldType.ToString().Contains(".Dictionary")){
                _str += "\t" + info.Name;
                _str += ".typeof(" + info.FieldType + "): ";
                _str += ((info.GetValue(behave)!=null)?info.GetValue(behave):"null");
                _str += "\n";
                // this is where the work on Dictionary should happen
            }else if(info.FieldType.ToString().Contains("String")){
                _str += "\t" + info.Name;
                _str += ".typeof(" + info.FieldType + "): ";
                _str += ((info.GetValue(behave)!=null)?info.GetValue(behave):"null");
                _str += "\n";
            }else{
                _str += "\t" + info.Name;
                _str += ".typeof(" + info.FieldType + "): ";
                _str += ((info.GetValue(behave)!=null)?info.GetValue(behave):"null");
                _str += "\n";
            }
        }
    }
    return _str;
}
```

Comment: Dude, don't try to reinvent the wheel, use LINQ

Comment: @HighCore could you show an example of what you mean, or point me to something that shows what you mean?

Comment: Post some code of what you're trying to achieve. Also, Why don't you just `list.OfType<YourType>()`? I don't understand what are you trying to do.

Comment: OMG dude, what in the world is that? are you trying to destroy the Earth? and why are you doing egyptian braces?

Comment: actually this is rather light, and performant the most expensive thing I do is LINQ, and even you were suggesting that. reflection is "relatively" cheap. I am not looking to use Invoke, so performance is not really be touched, and this is only ever to be used for testing.

Comment: Do you really need the infinitesimal gain in performance so much to justify sacrificing your readability in such a horrible way?

Comment: the bracing style, and the code formatting has nothing to do with the question. the question is how would I effectively get to the elements of a Collections.Generic collection

Comment: @gardian06 the answer to that is: `collection.OfType<SomeType>()`. I still have no idea what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @HIghCore could you please formalize your answer with either a working example, or a reference to a working example?

Comment: @gardian06 no I cannot do that because I'm unsure what you're asking. Therefore I cannot create any code sample. Please clarify your intention and why do you need this horrible reflection hack to begin with.

Comment: as the start of my question reads I just want to from a starting point get all Fields the object contains, and then reflect on each one so that I can output their name, type, and value, and then if those fields point to a collection, or class go to that, and repeat the process. the only thing I am truly having problems with is Collections. hence the title, the body of the question as well as the code sample.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for most collections. Maybe it will work for you.

```
    object fieldValue = fieldInfo.GetValue( obj );

    if ( fieldValue is IEnumerable )
      {
      foreach ( var item in (IEnumerable)fieldValue )
        {
        //do your stuff
        Console.WriteLine(item.GetType());
        Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
      }
```